Powershell still outputting weird characters despite being set for Unicode
In Powershell I'm trying to output a simple bullet (•) to be appended to a string.
However, when I run the code, instead of showing the bullet I see:â€¢ instead.
Earlier on in the code, I have the following two lines set:
# Earlier on
# Force UTF-8 Encoding:
$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

...

$version_str    = "•" * $version

$fullname = $fullname + " " + $version_str


...

# Write the processed data to a CSV file
$outputData | Out-File -FilePath $outputCsv -Encoding UTF8


For example if $version = 3 and $fullname = Paul. I should see Paul ••• but instead, I see: Paul â€¢â€¢â€¢ in the output file and the terminal.
If it matters much, this happens both when I run the code in Visual Studio and in Powershell itself.
My current version is 5.1.22621.4249

Since the problem occurs with string literals in your source code, the likeliest explanation is that your script file is misinterpreted by the Windows PowerShell engine, which happens if the script is saved as UTF-8 without a BOM (this is no longer a problem in PowerShell (Core) 7). Try saving your script as UTF-8 with BOM.
See the linked duplicate for details.

As an aside: $OutputEncoding and [Console]::OutputEncoding only matter with respect to communication with external programs.

Aha. Saving it as UTF-8 w/ BOM was the fix. Does this mean the file that is output is now also UTF8 w/BOM as well?

Glad to hear it. Saving  your source code as UTF-8 with BOM solely ensures that it is read correctly by Windows PowerShell, and is unrelated to the behavior of file-writing cmdlets such as Out-File. That said, passing -Encoding UTF8 to such cmdlets in Windows PowerShell invariably creates UTF-8 files with BOM (in PowerShell 7, it would create BOM-less UTF-8 files and is redundant, as said encoding is the consistent default there). See this answer for more information.

Also as for the $OutputEncoding that was done as there is also a line in the original code that also outputs the same jibberish too. But changing to UTF8BOM fixed both problems.

I don't fully understand, but note that the $OutputEncoding preference variable, as noted, solely relates to external programs; specifically, it controls what encoding is used to send data to external programs via the pipeline (to their stdin stream).

@mklement0 My fault. I thought changing the Console encoding controlled how it was output to the console readout. Tweaking some other things, namely upgrading to PS7 and changing the -Encoding to UTF8NoBOM , as well as changing the save file encoding to UTF8BOM gave me the result I was hoping for. Thanks again.

Glad to hear it, @PaulWilliams. Note that in PowerShell 7, -Encoding UTF8NoBOM is the same as -Encoding utf8, which is actually the consistent default there. In other words: In PowerShell 7, if  you want BOM-less UTF-8, you don't need an -Encoding argument at all.
